# Using Windows Store App class library for WinRT (ARM) application

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have created a Windows Store class library. This contains some user controls and custom controls. The output type of this library is .dll

I am able to this .dll in my Windows Store Apps and the application works good on the simulator and the local machine. I am using Visual 2012 RC with Windows 8 RTM

I also plan run this app on WinRT (ARM) device.

My question is: For running the application on WinRT (ARM) device do I need to create a .winmd file or I can use the .dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you will not be able to develop on an ARM device your only choice of deployment is to build it, publish it and download it. There may some way of pushing apps in a company network, but I don't know the details there.

An interesting blog about how you could approach deplyment to ARM: http://tech.xster.net/tips/how-to-debugdeploy-winrtwindows-8-app-to-arm-tablet/

However, if you are only considering what you need to do when you submit you app to Windows Store there is a different story. Before uploading to Windows Store you create an application package by selecting the menu options Project / Store / Create App Package in VIsual Studio 2012.

If you app is pure WinRT then you can select Architecture Neutral which will create an application package which will on all devices; x86, x64 and ARM. Visual Studio will take care of what needs to be done...